# Pandoc Word to Dokuwiki heading conversion

Tags: docx, pandoc, heading, dokuwiki

I am trying to convert a word docx file to dokuwiki using the pandoc command line utility. There are no errors, and lists are correctly converted.

However, heading formats are not recognized at all. I set the headings in the word file using the styles. The dokuwiki format should then use the = to delineate different levels. This does not work. I tried with -f docs+styles but no luck.

Anybody know what I’m missing here?

Comment: You'll have to post your word document... but it should have the same format as the word document generated by `echo '# myheader' | pandoc -o output.docx`

Comment: Great that worked! I used the template document and used the headings in there. really didn't understand that from the pandoc guide... :P Thank you!

Comment: I think it should also work with the built-in heading styles... but that may depend on your Word version...

Comment: Strange... because I tried with a bunch of different ones and it didn't work... I am running Word 2016 for Mac, so maybe pandoc hasn't been updated for that? But seems strange 3 years in...

Comment: not sure, you can post a minimal .docx file with such a header on the pandoc-discuss mailing list, or unzip it and see what's the difference to the one generated by pandoc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template word file made available in pandoc contains the heading styles needed in word to correctly identify headers. The following command will place the template in the current directory:

```
echo '# myheader' | pandoc -o output.docx
```

1. Copy your text into this DOCX file.
2. Open the styles pane and scroll down to find all the styles named
   Heading 1, 2, etc...
3. Use these styles for the heading levels you want to use in the dokuwiki file
   (start with Heading 1 for the most top-level heading style).
4. Save this document and use it as the input for the pandoc
   conversion.
5. All headings will be converted to the correct dokuwiki formats.

Thanks to mb21 for the answer!